# IBAction unknown error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, ibaction

```
    - (IBAction)ButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender {


- (void) ButtonPressed: (id) sender
    {
        if (sender != self.done)
            return;
        if (self.zahlencode.text.length > 0)
        {
            zz =[self.zahlencode.text intValue];
            if(zz == a)
            {

                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1" sender:self];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

At Void ButtonPressed there is an Error that says `Use of undeclared ButtonPressed`
And if I use this without the action the App build crashes . I put there an Exception Breakpoint and it gives out this error

```
2014-03-19 10:19:53.295 AbteiRD[8873:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8a91780 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
(lldb)
```

Comment: did you forget brace **}** ? the right must is: `- (IBAction)ButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender { }`

Comment: Oh i thought I must be at the end of the void. Ill test it

Comment: why did you put the -(void) method inside the IBAction?

Comment: Why do i have now -1 what did I done wrong ? Sorry this was my first question here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot put a **void** function into **- (IBAction)ButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender** change it as follow:

```
    - (IBAction)ButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender {
       if (sender != self.done)
            return;
        if (self.zahlencode.text.length > 0)
        {
            zz =[self.zahlencode.text intValue];
            if(zz == a)
            {

                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1" sender:self];
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: I changed it but after I done this error appeared                    `2014-03-19 10:41:54.497 AbteiRD[9272:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8a81ca0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-03-19 10:42:01.280 AbteiRD[9272:70b] -[mainViewController ButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ab5be0
(lldb)`

Comment: after change your code. go to xib's file and remake your action for your **button**

Comment: I´ve done that but now a real huge error appeared thats the last part of it                                                                `<Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
(lldb) `

Comment: it seem you make many errors into your code. So, please post your source code then give me the link, so maybe I can help you.

Comment: [link](https://www.mediafire.com/?pk98us83nr54iz8) here is the source code

Comment: I saw into your code: declare `int a,b,c,zz;` as a global variable and assign it not right place. Change it: move `int a,b,c,zz;` into `@interface mainViewController (){
    int a,b,c,zz;
}` and assign a = 1, b= 2, c=3 into **viewDidLoad**. When I download your code, the source code not include images.

Comment: If you get any errors relate to images when build. please open the project, then chose **build phrase** and chose **copy bundle resources** ->click '+' to add images from your disk.After all it'll work OK.

Comment: Sorry for miss a thing: when you click on **Fertig** button-> the app crash. To fix it:chose **Main View Controller** and then chose: **Editor-> Embed In -> Navigation controller** to add navigation controller

Comment: Thanks everything is working now !